# Like PIVOT but values not discrete

Tags: sql, pivot, inequality

A table lists multiple events where each event has four attributes (columns), call them A, B, C, P

It would be simpleto pivot to get a table with columns for A, B, C, P=1, P=2, P=3, etc.

However, I need the columns to be A, B, C, P<1, P<2, P<3, etc.

In other words, if a row of the "simple" way were X, Y, Z, 7, 3, 5, 2 then what I actually need is X, Y, Z, 7, 10, 15, 17 because any P less than N is also less than N+1.

I know I can compute the values (X, Y, Z, 7, 10, 15, 17), load them into a temporary table, and pivot that, but maybe there's something simple that my SQL talents don't recognize immediately?

If it matters, the result will end up in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this should work.

```
SELECT
    A,
    B,
    C,
    SUM(CASE WHEN P < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN P < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN P < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN P < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P4
FROM
    Events
GROUP BY
    A,
    B,
    C
```

This is not dynamic. For example, if you have a row in there with P=4 then it will not add a row for P<5. It's also using strictly < and not <=.

Comment: Thank you, that did work.  It was almost what I meant by compute them, but simpler than loading a temporary table.  I thought I had checked it as an answer long ago.